# How to correct "preload key requests" performance problem on lighthouse with vue-cli and vue.config.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, lighthouse

I use Vue-CLI to build my vue.js project.

When I use lighthouse, I see big opportunities of performance: "Preload Key requests" with these warnings:

- A preload  was found for ".../js/chunk-vendors.505a9ffc.js" but was not used by the browser. Check that you are using the `crossorigin` attribute properly.
- A preload  was found for ".../js/app.a1661204.js" but was not used by the browser. Check that you are using the `crossorigin` attribute properly.
- A preload  was found for ".../css/chunk-vendors.89b73702.css" but was not used by the browser. Check that you are using the `crossorigin` attribute properly.
- A preload  was found for ".../css/app.9ea691b0.css" but was not used by the browser. Check that you are using the `crossorigin` attribute properly.

Does anyone have a solution to fix it with Vue-CLI and vue.config.js to modify the webpack config?

And can you explain the problem?

Comment: How does the generated `index.html` look like?

Comment: For each js file there is one preload and one script module with crossoriginn="anonymous"


<link href="/js/chunk-vendors~205977d4.31133be7.js" rel="modulepreload" as="script" crossorigin="anonymous">
...
...
<script type="module" src="/js/chunk-vendors~205977d4.31133be7.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

Comment: So this is in fact [Modern Mode](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/browser-compatibility.html#modern-mode) build...

Comment: Ah yes, I see. So I have to put crossorigin option to "use-credentials". Is it right?
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to configure [crossOriginLoading](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputcrossoriginloading) in webpack config file.

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    crossOriginLoading: 'anonymous'
  }
};
```

Not sure if you have a separate webpack config file or not, but if you are using default [vue.config.js](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#simple-configuration) file, you can use `configureWebpack` option for the same:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
        crossOriginLoading: 'anonymous'
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: hmm, this seems to solve my problem but what does this exactly do?

Comment: It sets crossorigin attribute when adding `link` tags for scripts, you can read bit more about it at: https://web.dev/preload-critical-assets/#preloading-javascript-files

Answer (score 0):

I've used **preload-webpack-plugin** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/preload-webpack-plugin)

```
const PreloadWebpackPlugin = require('preload-webpack-plugin');

// adds <style> tag with preload
module.exports = {
  ...,
  plugins: [
    ...,
    new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
        rel: 'preload',
        as: 'style',
        include: ['main', 'profile', 'search'], // can be 'allChunks' or 'initial' or see more on npm page
        fileBlacklist: [/\.map|.js/], // here may be chunks that you don't want to have preloaded
    })
  ]
}
```